# Sump pump stops working

Tags: pump, sump

I purchased and installed a Zoeller some pump approximately five weeks ago. It worked great for one month and not a drop of water the basement. It has recently stopped working in the evenings and end up with a couple inches of water in the basement. I notice the float is all the way up when it has stopped working and all I have to do is gently tap the discharge pipe or the sump pump itself, and then it would immediately kick on and pump all the water out quickly. A contact Zoeller, and he stated it was most likely an air bubble. But he gave no indication on how to fix it even after I have emailed him back to additional times. I welcome any advice, basement has flooded three times in last week.    I did drill a weep hole

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Adding a couple of pictures of the sump pump would help us help you.

Comment: Sounds like the float switch is failing, possibly due to a manufacturing defect or poor design. I'd request a replacement.

Comment: If you buy an item like this at say Home Depot or  Lowes, they will exchange the item under the warranty, just keep the sales receipt.  A sump pump that is not abused should last years not a few weeks.